# Disable onItemClick for recyclerView native ads in addOnItemTouchListener

Tags: java, android, onclick

In my `recyclerView` i display menu item and `admob native ads` then i have added `addOnItemTouchListener` to select multiple item.

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, recyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                if (isMultiSelect)
                    multi_select(position);
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Details Page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
                if (!isMultiSelect) {
                    multiSelectList = new ArrayList<>();
                    isMultiSelect = true;
                    FVideosAdapter.enableOption(false);

                    if (mActionMode == null) {
                        mActionMode = startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
                    }
                }
                multi_select(position);
            }
        }));
```

> Now how do i disable `onItemClick` for `UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE:` when `isMultiSelect` is `true` ?
> I don't want to include `UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE` for `multiselect`.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        switch (viewType) {
            case UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
                UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd = (UnifiedNativeAd) videosPath.get(position);
                populateNativeAdView(nativeAd, ((UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder) holder).getAdView());
                break;
            case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
            default:
                final FolderVideoAdapterViewHolder folderVideoAdapterViewHolder = (FolderVideoAdapterViewHolder) holder;
                final FolderVideoModel folderVideoModel = (FolderVideoModel) videosPath.get(position);
                folderVideoAdapterViewHolder.videoName.setText(folderVideoModel.getFileName());
                folderVideoAdapterViewHolder.duration.setText(folderVideoModel.getDuration());
                folderVideoAdapterViewHolder.size.setText(folderVideoModel.getSize());

                if(selected_usersList.contains(videosPath.get(position)))
                    ((FolderVideoAdapterViewHolder) holder).videoPath.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.list_item_selected_state));
                else
                    ((FolderVideoAdapterViewHolder) holder).videoPath.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.list_item_normal_state));
        }
    }
```

detailed multi-select code is [here](https://github.com/jaisonfdo/MultiSelectRecyclerVIew)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable onItemClick for UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE when isMultiSelect is true you should change your **onItemClick** method like below:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
     int viewType = recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemViewType(position);
     if(viewType == UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE && isMultiSelect) {
         return;
     }

     if (isMultiSelect)
           multi_select(position);
     else
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Details Page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and if you want to disable the long click from an AdView to prevent starting the multiselect process change your **onItemLongClick** method like below:

```
@Override
public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
    int viewType = recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemViewType(position);
    if(viewType == UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE) {
        return;
    }

    if (!isMultiSelect) {
        multiSelectList = new ArrayList<>();
        isMultiSelect = true;
        FVideosAdapter.enableOption(false);

        if (mActionMode == null) {
            mActionMode = startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
        }
    }
    multi_select(position);
}
```

Comment: And how do i detect `setOnClickListener` , Inside adapter `ViewHolder` i had two `setOnClickListener` one to for **opening details page** and another for **display option in bottom sheet**. Now how do i detect which view holder is clicked inside `onItemClick` ?

Comment: To detect which view holder is clicked inside onItemClick just put this line of code: RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);

Comment: Can I add `addOnItemTouchListener` inside adapter?

Comment: Of course just override the below function inside your adapter:   @Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);} and after the line super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView) do recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener